# UILocalNotification Fires Correctly, but does not Appear at top of Home Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

I have a strange issue using local notifications. The notification appears to work perfectly in the simulator. However, when using it on the device, the notification does not show that "fold down" at the top of the screen when it is fired. I know the alert is working because the badge number appears on my app icon, and if I slide down and look at all notifications, the new notification is listed. For some reason I just don't see it happening on the top of the home screen. I have also checked the app's notification settings on the device and it is set to show at the top.

Here is sample code in my .m file.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

UILocalNotification *_localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

_localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];

_localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

_localNotification.alertBody = @"You are notified";

_localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

_localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication 
sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:_localNotification];
```

Any help would be fantastic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply restarted the iPhone and it worked just fine. Weird.